# Switching Views in wpf mvvm

Tags: mvvm, view, datatemplate, contentcontrol

I have 2 views login and usermodule.I want to switch to usermodule if login is success.I  have made datatemplates in mainwindow and a content control which gets bind by currentviewmodel.I made a switchview method in MainWindowViewModel which is called after successful login.As the login is successful the currentviewmodel gets changed to usermoduleviewmodel bur the view is not changing.

I have done like this:
MainWinodow.xaml

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type VM:LoginViewModel}">
        <local:LoginView></local:LoginView>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type VM:MenuViewModel}">
        <local:MenuWindow />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type VM:UserModuleMapViewModel}">
        <local:UserModuleMapView />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ContentPresenter x:Name="Pages" Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}" 
    Grid.Row="1"/>
</Grid>
```

**MainWindow.cs**

```
 MainWindowViewModel mainVM = new MainWindowViewModel();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = mainVM;

    }
```

**MainWindowViewModel.cs**

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    readonly LoginViewModel _loginViewModel = new LoginViewModel();
    readonly MenuViewModel _menuViewModel = new MenuViewModel();
    readonly UserModuleMapViewModel _usermodmapViewModel = new UserModuleMapViewModel();

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        CurrentViewModel = _loginViewModel;
    }

    private ViewModelBase _currentViewModel;

    public ViewModelBase CurrentViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return _currentViewModel;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_currentViewModel == value)
                return;
            _currentViewModel = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CurrentViewModel");
        }
    }

    public void switchView()
    {
        if (CurrentViewModel == _loginViewModel)
        {
            CurrentViewModel = _usermodmapViewModel;
        }
        else
        {
            CurrentViewModel = _loginViewModel;
        }
    }

}
```

LoginViewModel.cs

```
public LoginModel objmodel { get; set; }
    public ICommand LoginCommand { get; set; }
    public LoginModel _selectedItem { get; set; }
    public LoginModel SelectedItem
    {
        get { return _selectedItem; }
        set
        {
            _selectedItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("comboBoxItems");//need to check now its working properly
        }
    }

    readonly UserModuleMapViewModel _usermodmapViewModel = new UserModuleMapViewModel();

    public LoginViewModel()
    {
        getjobkeycodeCombobox();
        objmodel = new LoginModel();
        LoginCommand = new RelayCommand(() => Login());

    }
 public void Login()
    {
        try
        {
            UserIdInfo info = new UserIdInfo();

            {
                objmodel.job_Code_Key = SelectedItem.job_Code_Key;
                info.EMP_NO = objmodel.EMP_NO;
                info.Password = objmodel.Password;
                info.Job_Code_Key = objmodel.job_Code_Key;
                if (objmodel.EMP_NO == null || objmodel.EMP_NO == "" || objmodel.Password == null || objmodel.Password == "")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please Enter the inputs of all the fields..!!");
                }
                else
                {
                    UserIdBL uidBL = new UserIdBL();
                    if (uidBL.isvalid(info))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Success..!!");

                        MainWindowViewModel mwvm = new MainWindowViewModel();
                        mwvm.CurrentViewModel = _usermodmapViewModel;
                        //Messenger.Default.Send(new NotificationMessage("LoginSuccess"));

                    }
                    else
                    {
                    }
                }
            }
        }


    }
```

What mistake is done?Am I missing something >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the ContentPresenter is not updating is because the view is bound to a different instance of `MainWindowViewModel`. So the `MainWindow` DataContext is bound to an instance which is created here:

```
// MainWindow.cs
MainWindowViewModel mainVM = new MainWindowViewModel();
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = mainVM;
}
```

While the `LoginViewModel` creates a new instance of `MainWindowViewModel` which is not bound to anything:

```
// LoginViewModel.cs
MainWindowViewModel mwvm = new MainWindowViewModel();
mwvm.CurrentViewModel = _usermodmapViewModel;
```

That's why when you set `mwvm.CurrentViewModel` property in the `Login` method the binding is not triggered.

So to achieve what you are trying to do you can subscribe `MainWindowViewModel` to login success message and set the current viewmodel there. Here is a simple example with MVVM Light messenger:

```
// LoginViewModel.cs
if (uidBL.isvalid(info))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Success..!!");

    // MainWindowViewModel mwvm = new MainWindowViewModel();
    // mwvm.CurrentViewModel = _usermodmapViewModel;

    // send message to all subscribers
    Messenger.Default.Send(new NotificationMessage("LoginSuccess"));
}

// MainWindowViewModel.cs
Messenger.Default.Register<NotificationMessage>(this, (message) =>
{
    switch (message.Notification)
    {
        case "LoginSuccess":
            CurrentViewModel = _usermodmapViewModel;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
});
```

Comment: Alex how to write that piece of code in mainwindow view model

Comment: @Rohit You can put it in the ViewModel constructor

Comment: Alex Many Thanks man..It worked exactly the way i required.But i have a query ,shoouid i ask here or post a new question

Comment: @Rohit If it is not related to "Switching Views in wpf mvvm" subject, I think the right thing to do is to create a new question

Comment: It is somewhat to the view concept...I have a menu view and different menuitems (say 4 items) each item has 2 views and i want to open one view inside menu view...I guess its somewhat parent-child view concept

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use Prism's IEventAggregator. You'd create a class that was a PubSub event e.g.

public class LoginSuccessfulEvent : PubSubEvent { }

then subscribe to that event in the main viewmodel using an instance of the event aggregator e.g.

myEventAggregator.GetEvent().Subscribe((obj) => { SomeMethodInMainViewModel(obj); });

then publish the event from within the login viewmodel when the login was successful e.g.

myEventAggregator.GetEvent().Publish(someLocalObject);

I've successfully used this in one of my projects, but might not have updated the prism lib for 6 months, but as long as latest version has this functionality it should be good. Depends if you want a 3rd party lib in your project.

Or..

You could pass in an Action to the login view model constructor that pointed to a method on the main view model that set the current view model to the main viewmodel, and have the login viewmodel invoke that Action when login was successful